# Error after payment test with stripe where woocommerce pass empty object

Tags: php, wordpress

We are having this e-commerce website using wordpress with woocommerce and stripe payment gateway, and then we have our own backend system where it will trigger the webhook and woocommerce will push the order details to the backend system. Unfortunately the order details was empty, and there's some error on the wordpress:

> [error] 9116#9116: *754 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: slug was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->create_order, do_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, save_order_meta_data, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.

Any help on this?